# Glossary with no title

Tags: glossaries

I have a glossary printed in two columns, but the title is printed on the first columns:

[image]

If I print separatly the title I have:

[image]

How I can avoid to print again 'Glossario' with the command `\printglossary`?
I use the package `glossary`.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,11pt,twoside]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=17.5cm,paperheight=25cm, inner=1.25cm,outer=5.75cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[style=list,glossaryname=false,number=none]{glossary}
\makeglossary
\begin{document}
\glossary{name={Luce}, description={Radiazione elettromagnetica di particolare frequenza, percepibile dall'occhio umano. La lunghezza d'onda dello spettro luminoso varia da 1 nm (violetto estremo) a 1000 nm (rosso).}}

\glossary{name={Numero atomico}, description={Numero utilizzato per caratterizzare chimicamente un atomo. Corrisponde al numero di protoni presenti nel nucleo dell'atomo.}}

%\normalsize
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossario}
\newgeometry{inner=1.25cm,outer=1.25cm}
%\chapter*{Glossario}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\hfill \huge\textbf{Glossario}
\small  
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printglossary
\end{multicols}
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, regardless of the value of `\glossarytitle`, the package injects a `\chapter*` command, which causes column misalignment. To solve this, redefine the `\glossarytitle` macro to empty and enter your own `\chapter*` *before* the `multicols` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[style=list,number=none]{glossary}
\usepackage{multicol}

\renewcommand\glossaryname{Glossario}
\renewcommand\glossarytitle{}
\makeglossary

\begin{document}
\chapter{The First Chapter}
This is a test\glossary{name={test}, description={test}} of glossary functionality.

\section{The First Section}
Here we will test and check\glossary{name={check}, description={test2}} the glossary.

\chapter*{\glossaryname}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printglossary
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Gives output:
[image: MWE output]

You might consider switching to the [`glossaries` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries), since `glossary` is obselete and the new package has more flexible styling. Migration instructions are provided [here](http://ctan.unixbrain.com/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossary2glossaries.pdf).

Comment: Yes, I dont like the 'Glossario' title over the first column only, but on the top of both columns. For this it is necessary to make glossaryname equals to null string...

Comment: Setting `glossaryname` to null string will still leave vertical space where the title would have gone, so your columns will not be aligned. To achieve what you want, redefine `glossarytitle` to empty and manually insert a `\chapter*` before the `multicols` environment. I will update my answer above.

Comment: Thanks it works very well only adding to my source code the line:

\renewcommand\glossarytitle{}

before \makeglossary.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the option `glossaryname` is not a valid option for the package `glossary`.

I suggest you to redefine the `theglossary` environment so that the glossary is printed in two columns. That is, add the following lines in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{%
\glossarytitle\glossarypreamble%
\begin{multicols}{2}\@bef@reglos%
}{%
\@ftergl@s\end{multicols}%
\noindent\glossarypostamble}
\makeatother
```

Also, if you want a glossary entry in the toc, it suffices to add the option `toc=true` when loading `glossary` (no need for the `\addcontentsline` line):

```
\usepackage[style=list,number=none,toc=true]{glossary}
```

MWE (I've also loaded `babel` with the `italian` option):

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth=17.5cm,paperheight=25cm, inner=1.25cm,outer=5.75cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[style=list,number=none,toc=true]{glossary}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{%
\glossarytitle\glossarypreamble%
\begin{multicols}{2}\@bef@reglos%
}{%
\@ftergl@s\end{multicols}%
\noindent\glossarypostamble}
\makeatother

\makeglossary

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\glossary{name={Luce}, description={Radiazione elettromagnetica di particolare frequenza, percepibile dall'occhio umano. La lunghezza d'onda dello spettro luminoso varia da 1 nm (violetto estremo) a 1000 nm (rosso).}}

\glossary{name={Numero atomico}, description={Numero utilizzato per caratterizzare chimicamente un atomo. Corrisponde al numero di protoni presenti nel nucleo dell'atomo.}}

%\normalsize

\newgeometry{inner=1.25cm,outer=1.25cm}
%\chapter*{Glossario}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\small
\printglossary

\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I already have this output! But I want 'Glossario' put on the top of both columns.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Sorry for the late reply, I was going to bed. Now it does what you want.