# Print glossaries without title

Tags: glossaries

For now I print my glossaries in document using command `\printglossaries` from `glossaries` package. Unfortunately the title of glossaries messes up my document formatting in a way that blank page appears before the title.

In documentation I found command `\setglossarysection` which by using in my document as:

```
\setglossarysection{subsubsection}
```

fixes the issue of blank page before the glossaries, but the title still remains.

What are the possibilities of printing glossaries without the title?

Comment: Does [this link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156723/glossary-with-no-title?rq=1) answer your question?

Comment: @StefanBollmann That link is a question about the obsolete `glossary` package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sectioning command is inserted via `\glossarysection[toc title]{title}`, so just redefine that command to do nothing:

```
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
```

However, it might be better if you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates the blank page problem, as there might be some other issue involved.

Comment: Thank you. How can I remove the whitespace that gets printed before the glossary actually starts?

Comment: @raffamaiden I recommend you post a question with a MWE that demonstrates the white space because it depends on the document class and glossary style.