# The List of abbreviations should be in a table

Tags: glossaries

The image below is a list of abbreviations I currently have, I'm trying to find how to add borders, in a table with no headers but with entries separated by lines.

Current MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-longragged}
\setglossarystyle{altsuper4col}
\makeglossaries
    
\begin{document}

\newacronym{abcd}{ABCD}{Any body can Dance}
\newacronym{mi}{MI}{Mission Impossible}
\newacronym{usa}{USA}{United States of America}

\gls{abcd} and \gls{mi} are movies from \gls{usa}.

\printglossary[nonumberlist, type=\acronymtype, toctitle=List of Abbreviations, title = List of Abbreviations]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Please make a simple test to understand our situation, the reader and helping people: A) copy your posted code into a new .tex file; B) compile it; C) add more code needed to make it compile AND show your problem; D) make sure, there is no unrelated line of code. // Next, EDIT your question and update your code MWE. Thanks // If you can, draw a sketch of your desired result, so even me understands it.

Comment: Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using. You have described your code as **MWE** when it is not a MWE, as it cannot compile without effort on the part of people who you want to help.

Comment: So, I had added a proper minimum working example.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you keep reverting the tag edits to your question? As far as I can see, none of the tags you added have direct relevance to your question, yet you keep removing the tag `glossaries` (which seems extremely relevant).

Comment: I'm really sorry, I thought the I added the glossaries tag accidentally and thought, tex might be the correct tag. Quite new to stack exchange and its inner workings. A lot of things are happening on this page, and didn't know that someone can edit the tags which were set by me.

Comment: @VB not to worry, it's a learning experience, editing questions the aim is usually to preserve and clarify the OP's meaning, and you can revert if you feel necessary, but with tags in particular what feels relevant often isn't (the editor you're using doesn't actually matter if it's about what code will produce this, similar for `pdftex` and `luatex` as they treat most code the same way so only useful tagging if there's something specific), while what often matters most is/are the package(s) you are trying to use features of (in this case mainly `glossaries`)

Answer (score 1):

The [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) of [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) talks through various styles.
Starting with `altsuper4col` as your example code does, it looks like the `altsuper4colborder` does the job for adding a border.

[image: Table of abbreviations with borders drawn around and vertical lines dividing columns]

However, this has vertical lines separating columns, rather than horizontal lines separating the entries.
None of the other styles listed as predefined in 13.1.4 Longtable Styles (Ragged Right) seem to do the job, but 13.2 Defining your own glossary style points to `\newglossarystyle` which can (using an existing style as a basis) create our own.
Now, looking at the [package code](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-code.pdf) of [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries), we can see what goes into `altsuper4col` in Sec 3.8 Glossary Styles using supertabular environment (glossary-super.sty).
First, for borders we can modify the definition of `theglossary` used by `altsuper4colborder`, and remove the internal vertical lines given by `|` in the table specification.
Then, we can take the the definition of `glossentry` used by `supercol`, and append `\hline` so a horizontal line is drawn after each.
Finally, a blank line is added if a group skip is set, to which we also need to append an `\hline`, again modifying the the code used by `super4col`.

```
\newglossarystyle{vb}{
\setglossarystyle{super4col}

\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\tablehead{\hline}\tabletail{\hline}%
    \begin{supertabular}%
        {|lp{\glsdescwidth}lp{\glspagelistwidth}|}}%
    {\end{supertabular}}%

\renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1} &
    \glossentrysymbol{##1} & ##2\tabularnewline\hline
}%

\ifglsnogroupskip
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
\else
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{& & & \tabularnewline\hline}%
\fi
}
```

which gives when used (`\setglossarystyle{vb}`)

[image: Table of abbreviations with borders drawn around and horizontal lines separating entires]

The blank lines come from the group skip (gap between entries beginning with a different letters), according to the manual it should be possible to disable locally by passing `nogroupskip` to `\printglossaries`, for some reason that isn't working for me locally, but does as an option to the package, you can disable it for the style altogether by replacing

```
\ifglsnogroupskip
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
\else
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{& & & \tabularnewline\hline}%
\fi
```

with `\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}`.

Finally, to remove the title we can take [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175261) and use `\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}`.

---

All this said, `\setglossarystyle{long-booktabs}` (which requires `\usepackage{glossary-longbooktabs}`) looks better to me for less effort.

[image: Table of abbreviations with top/bottom rules and a rule under the headings]